# Netaddr returns NameError instead of ImportError

Tags: python, error-handling, importerror

netaddr python module skips ImportError. I had to create a function to use try/finally to catch the ImportError then redo the try/except to return a print value. Was wondering if there was an easier way to catch the ImportError??

```
import json
import base64
try:
    netaddr_mod()
except:
    print("ImportError: pip install netaddr")

def netaddr_mod():
    try:
        import netaddr
    finally:
        import netaddr
```

I was seeing some other fixes within global variables, but nothing similar to this import fix. Would be fantastic to find an easier way around this, but this way could work for now.

Comment: Hi you can see information off python exception try catch block at this link : https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a function doesn't exist until the `def` statement defines it. So if you call it ahead of defining it you will get a `NameError`.

So, define `netaddr_mod()` *before* you try to call it. Otherwise line 4 of your code will raise a `NameError`. The message *says* it is an `ImportError` but your code is not actually checking to see what the exception is. If you modify the code like this:

```
try:
    netaddr_mod()
except:
    print("ImportError: pip install netaddr")
    raise
```

You will get

```
ImportError: pip install netaddr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 2, in <module>
    netaddr_mod()
NameError: name 'netaddr_mod' is not defined
```

Here you see the message about the `ImportError` that you think it is, followed by the traceback that tells you what the exception really is.

*Moral:* Don't use bare exceptions because they mask or misreport other issues with the code. Do an explicit `except ImportError:` if you are trying to trap import errors. Then if you get a different exception you will at least know what it is.

Comment: Thanks! This was more of my work around to solve the main issue. The main issue is that the netaddr module does not return an error when using the normal try/except.

`try:`
    `import netaddr`
`except ImportError:`
    `raise ImportError`

It would completely passover the import and result to a name error. using that same try/except and then additional code: 

`bla = raw_input("Give an Ip")`
`if netaddr.valid_ipv4(bla) is True:`
    `print("Valid")`